# ampersand JSON and Angular6

Tags: angular, angular6

I have problems with ampersand when try to construct the URL in my service:

```
addPost(post: Post){
        let json = JSON.stringify(post);
        //let params = 'json='+json.replace('&','y');
        let params = 'json='+json;
        let headers = new Headers ({'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'});

        return this._http.post(this.url+'posts', params, {headers: headers})
            .pipe(map((res: Response) => res.json()));
    }
```

[let params = 'json='+json;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnv7N.jpg)

The following image is without replacing the ampersand

If i replace the ampersand for any character like "y" for example:

```
let params = 'json='+json.replace('&','y');
```

The result is like this:
[json.replace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nddS.jpg)

How can i pass the ampersand as a character?.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What do you mean "problems"? It needs to be URL-escaped.

Comment: I'm confused about why you need to replace the ampersand at all... what is `post`?

Comment: It's for make a POST to an API. I wouldn't replace the ampersand, my problem is, if i use this symbol in any field in my form, there's no information saved in the database.

Answer (score 0):

This is a POST, so your body will be passed as a body and not as URL params.

With either URL parameters or boy, the `HttpClient` would take care of serializing them for you. You do not need to and should not try to serialize them before passing them to the `HttpClient`.

Just like the method signature and Angular docs say, just pass your body as a parameter to `http.post()`:

```
addPost(post: Post){
        let headers = new Headers ({'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'});

        return this._http.post(this.url + '/posts', post, {headers: headers})
            .pipe(map((res: Response) => res.json()));
    }
```

Don't serialize the body to JSON beforehand. Also of note, the new `HttpClient` will also parse the response from JSON, so depending on your version, the `map(s => s.json())` isn't needed.